# Delete Confirmation Window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

```
<div id="modalWindow">
    <button id="yes" class="k-button">Yes</button>
    <button id="no" class="k-button">No</button>
</div>
<script>
var wnd;
$(document).ready(function() {
    wnd = $("#modalWindow").kendoWindow({
        title: "Delete confirmation",
        modal: true,
        visible: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 300
    }).data("kendoWindow");

});

function DeleteItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var grid = this;
    var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
    wnd.center().open();

    $("#yes").click(function() {
        grid.removeRow(row);
        wnd.close();
    });

    $("#no").click(function() {
        wnd.close();
    });
}
</script>
```

Hello,

I'm using a Telerik Grid with a custom button column that open a window for the confirmation to delete the related row. 
When I click the button of one row and I confirm the delete it works properly.
When I click the button of one row, cancel the delete, then click another button of another row and submit the delete it delete every row of the grid.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: try returning `false` after `wnd.close()` in `no` click!!

Comment: provide a js-fiddle?

Comment: You're rebinding the `click` event every time you open the window. Actually it's not rebinding, it's re-adding the same event handler. That means that on the second `click` event you'll be calling the handle two time, on the third, three times and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call the `DeleteItem` function you are setting up a handler for the `#yes` button to delete a specific row. Even if you cancel and select a different row, the handler was already set, and will run on a future click of the button.

To avoid this, you should clear the click event handler set up previously before setting the new one:

```
function DeleteItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var grid = this;
    var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
    wnd.center().open();

    $("#yes").unbind('click').click(function () {
        grid.removeRow(row);
        wnd.close();
    });

    $("#no").unbind('click').click(function () {
        wnd.close();
    });
}
```